# how to create a good gui for welcome screen

Tags: android, user-interface

I am trying to create a logo with white screen butI don't know if there is a simple wayto do it on android.And yes I know that I have --->http://www.droiddraw.org/ but still it dosent help me.and if I create it how it can work on some mobiles because of the screen size

thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well once you have some kind of logo you want to use, you can just put it inside an ImageView and set the layout_height and layout_width to fill_parent. That way it would be stretched to match the screen.

I suggest making a Splash activity which extends AsyncTask.

For example:

```
 public class Splash extends Activity
 {
      @Override
      public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
      {
           super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
           setContentView(R.layout.splash);

           GotoHome go = new GotoHome(this);
           go.execute();
      }

      private class GotoHome extends AsyncTask(Void, Void, Void)
      {
           static final long waitTime = 1 * 4000L;
           Context context;
           long preTime;

           public GotoHome(Context context)
           {
                this.context = context;
           }


        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(Void result) 
        {
            super.onPostExecute(result);

            startActivity(new Intent(context, YOUR ACTIVITY HERE));
            finish();
        }



        @Override
        protected void onPreExecute() 
        {
            super.onPreExecute();
            preTime = System.currentTimeMillis();
        }



        @Override
        protected Void doInBackground(Void... args) 
        {
            long timeDifference = System.currentTimeMillis() - preTime;
            if(timeDifference < preTime)
            {
                try
                {
                    Thread.sleep(splashTime - timeDifference);
                }
                catch(InterruptedException ie)
                {
                    Log.d("GotoHome", ie.getMessage());
                }
            }
            return null;
        }
      }
```

Then your splash.xml would look something like tihs:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" 
    android:background="@drawable/splash_image"
    >
</LinearLayout>
```

splash_image would be your logo.

Hope it helps :-)

Answer (score 0):

Another nice trick is to set the Activity Theme to be transparent.  Add this to the activity that will display the splash screen.

```
android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Translucent"
```

Then create a view that is centered in the screen.  Thus you have created a nice splash screen - to really set it off add a border and a gradient background or background pattern with your logo over the top of it.

Now just create a delayed thread to launch your application activity and finish the splash screen activity.  Now when a user opens your application the splash screen displays for your delay length (2-3 seconds is best) then loads the application.  Make sure you apply the logic to determine if the application is already running, this way if the application is open in the background and the icon is clicked again instead of showing the splash screen you can send and intent to bring the application to the front.

Hope this helps.